# jQuery - Understandiing `this` inside of step-animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have each function, inside I have animate with step function.
When I try to call $(this) and call to the selector of the current each - it doesn't work and give me some object (probably of the animate step function)

How can I reach the $(this) of the each element selector???

my code:

```
$(".animateNumber").each(function(){
    var selector = $(this);
    jQuery({ counter: 0 }).animate({
        counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        step: function() {
            // problem: the $(this) not working - if change to `selector` working
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(this.counter));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply don't. You have a reference to the Object you want in `selector`, why would you insist to call `$(domNode)` over and over again? **use `selector`!**

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".animateNumber").each(function(i,v){
        jQuery({ counter: 0 }).animate({
            counter: $(v).text()
        }, {
            step: function() {
                $(v).text(Math.ceil(this.counter));
            }
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't work and give me some object

`this` at `step` would be the object `{ counter: 0 }` passed at call to `jQuery()`.

You can use `selector` or `$(this)` as selector to `.animate()`; use `now` parameter at `step` function to set value of `counter` at `.text()` call. Note, also the `fx` object at `step` function has a reference to `this` element at `elem` property. You can use an object defined outside of `.animate()` to pass at first parameter to set, reset animation properties using values at object.

Add `+` operator before `$(this).text()` to set `counter` value to `Number`.

Not certain what expected effect is, though `this` at `step` should be the current element at `.each()` iteration.

```js
var props = {from:0, to:100};
$(".animateNumber").each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        counter: props.to
    }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
          console.log(this, fx.elem)
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="animateNumber">0</div>
<div class="animateNumber">0</div>
<div class="animateNumber">0</div>
```

---

Using similar pattern to `js` at Question, you can set `selector` as a property `elem` of the object passed to `.animate()`, reference `this.elem` , `this.counter` at `step` function.

```js
$(".animateNumber").each(function() {
  var selector = $(this);
  jQuery({
    elem: selector,
    counter: 0
  }).animate({
    counter: +$(this).text()
  }, {
    step: function () {
      // problem: the $(this) not working - if change to `selector` working
      this.elem.text(Math.ceil(this.counter));
      console.log(this)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="animateNumber">1</div>
<div class="animateNumber">2</div>
<div class="animateNumber">3</div>
```